# Laravel Yajra Datatables custom button action

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, datatables

I'm using [yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons](https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons) and I can't find a doc useful enough to help me.

I'm using the create button from the package which looks like this:

[image]

It should redirect me to my route which is: http://laravel.blog/admin/posts/create

But it keeps on redirecting me to http://laravel.blog/admin/posts/creer

it translates 'create' into 'creer' and I have no idea why it would do that. I'm building the app in english only and never used french for routes or anything.

AdminPostsDatatable.php:

```php
/**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('adminpostsdatatable-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1, 'desc')
                    ->buttons(
                        Button::make('create'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    );
    }
```

admin.posts.index view:

```bladephp
@extends("layouts.app")

@section('content')

    <h1>Posts</h1>
    @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    {!! $dataTable->table() !!}
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    {!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
@endpush
```

routes:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                         | admin.                | Closure                                                                | web,auth                                             |
|        | POST      | admin/posts                   | admin.posts.store     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPostsController@store                        | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts                   | admin.posts.index     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPostsController@index                        | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/create            | admin.posts.create    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPostsController@create                       | web,auth                                             |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/posts/{post}            | admin.posts.update    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPostsController@update                       | web,auth                                             |
|        | DELETE    | admin/posts/{post}            | admin.posts.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPostsController@destroy                      | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/{post}/edit       | admin.posts.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPostsController@edit                         | web,auth
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont really know if it's the right way to do it but I've come up with this solution:

```php
Button::make('create')->action("window.location = '".route('admin.posts.create')."';"),
```

Comment: Why should we add window.location? Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
         public function html()
            {
                return $this->builder()
                            ->setTableId('adminpostsdatatable-table')
                            ->columns($this->getColumns())
                            ->minifiedAjax()
                            ->dom('Bfrtip')
                            ->orderBy(1, 'desc')   
                            ->parameters([
                            'buttons'      => 
                             [
                                [
                                    'text' =>'<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> ' . 'My custom button',
                                    'className' => 'My custom class'
                                ],
                                 'csv',
                                 'excel'
                             ],
                              ]);
            }
```

and if you want dropdown collection button

```
                        'buttons'      => 
                           [
                             "extend"=> 'collection',
                             "text"=> 'My Collection button',
                             "buttons" => 
                                 [ 
                                   'csv',
                                   'excel',
                                    [                
                                        [
                                           'text' =>'<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> ' . 'My custom button',
                                           'className' => 'My custom class'
                                        ],
                                     ] 
                                 ]
                           ],
```